# How do I convert a byte array back to an image consumable by a view in asp net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm converting uploaded images to byte arrays like so:

```
private byte[] GetByteArrayFromImage(IFormFile file)
{
    using (var target = new MemoryStream())
    {
        file.CopyTo(target);
        return target.ToArray();
    }
}
```

When looking for a solution to convert back to an image that I can show on-screen in an asp.net core view, I find this one:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(myByteArray);
Image image= Image.FromStream(ms);
```

But it doesn't work. The only reference I get for Image is `using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;` and there's no `FromStream` method for this.

I think my main issue here is that I don't actually *know* what type I need to be converting the byte array into so I can display it on a page?!

**edit** do I actually just need to convert it back to an `IFormFile` type?

Comment: _You_ don't display images on a web page (nor does your C# code), the browser does this. Either through the `<img src=... />` element (or background images for other elements), where you download the image data form an endpoint you create, or through inline base64-encoded image data. You can't use `(System.Drawing.)Image.FromStream()` for this.

Comment: What you probably want to search for is `data uri from byte array c#` You will need to know or be able to derive the appropriate mime type.

Comment: I'm thinking it will be easier to use the host folders and files to directly upload and retrieve images

Comment: Using `img src=` I just needed to convert the `byteArray` to a base64 string and append it to "data:image/gif;base64,"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was really simple. I just wasn't sure what to look for. Say I have an `ImageDisplayModel` with various properties, one of which should be a string `ImageSource`:

```
ImageDisplayModel.ImageSource = "data:image/gif;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(myByteArray);
```

And then in a view:

```
<img src="Model.ImageSource" />
```